# Unable to load an iframe on my site

Tags: iframe

I'm inserting an iframe on my webpage with the following code.

```
<iframe src="[url]" width="400" height="700">
```

But in the browser I only see a blank box. In the browser console I'm seeing the following message.

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: [url] does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

[url] is an https url. Accessing the [url] directly in the browser is working.

Can anyone tell me why it is not displaying?

Comment: (All you would have had to do to find the answer yourself, is type the error message into google. -1 for not making a reasonable effort.)

Answer (score 0):

Is a security restriction. If you want to be able to insert the iframe in your page, you must tell the owner/admin of the origin site, from where you get the content, to set the X-Frame-Options so that you could share his content

`X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

The site that you want to display in the iframe has blocked the ability to be shown in an iframe.

Try to get in contact with the website administrator to ask for permission or an alternative.